# How to break the strings into new line which are declared in array? Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, string

I wanted to break the one string in the set of array elements. 
The output will be display with a time interval.
Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var caption= document.getElementById('caption');
    var text=['Hey there please help me','solve the problem sleep BETTER.'];
                    function display(i){
                    if(i >= text.length){
                       i = 0;
                       }
                    caption.innerHTML = text[i];
                    setTimeout(function(){
                      display(i + 1)
                     }, 6000)

                   }
                   display(0)
     </script>
```

The output is: solve the problem sleep BETTER.
But I need something like this: solve the problem (In new line)
                                 sleep BETTER.

Html:

```
<div class= "content" >
h1><span id="caption"> </span></h1> 
</div>
```

I need to display the caption with a new line.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply overwriting the text content with `caption.innerHTML = text[i]`, you'll want to **append** to the content with `+=`. To output `solve the problem` and `sleep BETTER` onto new lines, you'll first want to separate and them out in the array, and then add an HTML line break (`<br />`) before outputting the new text:

```js
var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
var text = ['Hey there please help me', 'solve the problem', 'sleep BETTER.'];

function display(i) {
  if (i >= text.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  caption.innerHTML += "<br />" + text[i];
  setTimeout(function() {
    display(i + 1)
  }, 6000)
}

display(0)
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1><span id="caption"> </span></h1>
</div>
```

If you don't want the to repeat, simply set the functionality inside of an `if` statement that checks `if (i < text.length)`:

```js
var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
var text = ['Hey there please help me', 'solve the problem', 'sleep BETTER.'];

function display(i) {
  if (i < text.length) {
    caption.innerHTML += "<br />" + text[i];
    setTimeout(function() {
      display(i + 1)
    }, 6000)
  }
}

display(0)
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1><span id="caption"> </span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,  I need to overwrite the captions. I don't wanna display one by one.** Do you have any better solution? **